Wistia extract video id from url
I am trying to extract video id using regex. Here are some video url examples:
http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/26sk4lmiix
https://support.wistia.com/medias/26sk4lmiix

My regex:
var rx = /https?:\/\/(.+)?(wistia\.com|wi\.st)\/(medias|embed)\/*\/([^;\?]+)/,
_m = url.match(rx)
if(_m && _m[4])return _m[4]
else return false;

Regiex is not quite correct and is returning for exmaple:
iframe/26sk4lmiix


Assuming the video id is always the last section of the URL, split it by / and get the last element of the resulting array.

Does /https?:\/\/([^\/]+)?(wistia\.(?:com|net)|wi\.st)\/(medias|embed)(?:\/.*)?\/([^;?]+)/  solve the issue?

Did anything help or do you need more assistance with this issue?

If you just want to extract the last portion of the URL path component via regex, then just match on the patttern [^/]+$:


var url = "http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/26sk4lmiix";
var id = url.match(/[^/]+$/);
console.log(id);



You could also split the URL on forward slash, and retain the final component:


var url = "http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/26sk4lmiix";
var parts = url.split("/");
console.log(parts[parts.length-1]);




I am not sure if their url can have additional content with slashes.

Then I am not sure of my answer...or any other answers given here.  You should have mentioned this in your question.

Also, with your solution it doesnt even guarantee that this is wistia link.

Here is the code without using the regex pattern.
function getVideoId(url) {
  return url.split("/").pop();
}

const url1 = "http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/26sk4lmiix";
console.log(getVideoId(url1));

const url2 = "https://support.wistia.com/medias/26sk4lmiix";
console.log(getVideoId(url2));

Output of url1: 26sk4lmiix
Output of url2: 26sk4lmiix

If you want to keep your current group patterns intact, you may use
/https?:\/\/([^\/]+)?(wistia\.(?:com|net)|wi\.st)\/(medias|embed)(?:\/.*)?\/([^;?]+)/

The (.+)? is changed to ([^\/]+)? to make sure the first group value is only matching within the hostname part.
I changed (wistia\.com|wi\.st) to (wistia\.(?:com|net)|wi\.st) since you have such an example with wistia.net to match.
The (?:\/.*)? part makes sure you match anything before an expected value that is captured into Group 4.
